# How to use groupby and apply with polars

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-polars

I am breaking my head trying to figure out how to use `groupby` and `apply` in Python's library polars.

Coming from Pandas, I was using:

```
def get_score(df):
   return spearmanr(df["prediction"], df["target"]).correlation

correlations = df.groupby("era").apply(get_score)
```

But in polars, this doesn't work.

I tried several approaches, mainly around:

```
correlations = df.groupby("era").apply(get_score)
```

But this fails with the error message:

> 'Could net get DataFrame attribute '_df'. Make sure that you return a DataFrame object.: PyErr { type: <class 'AttributeError'>, value: AttributeError("'numpy.float64' object has no attribute '_df'"),

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a sample, please?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of `polars>=0.10.4` you can use the `pl.spearman_rank_corr` function.

If you want to use a custom function you could do it like this:

### Custom function on multiple columns/expressions

```py
import polars as pl
from typing import List
from scipy import stats

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "g": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5],
    "a": [2, 4, 5, 190, 1, 4, 1],
    "b": [1, 3, 2, 1, 43, 3, 1]
})

def get_score(args: List[pl.Series]) -> pl.Series:
    return pl.Series([stats.spearmanr(args[0], args[1]).correlation], dtype=pl.Float64)

(df.group_by("g", maintain_order=True)
 .agg(
    pl.apply(
        exprs=["a", "b"], 
        function=get_score).alias("corr")
 ))
```

### Polars provided function

```py
(df.group_by("g", maintain_order=True)
 .agg(
     pl.spearman_rank_corr("a", "b").alias("corr")
 ))
```

Both output:

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ g   ┆ corr │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0.5  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ -1e0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ NaN  │
└─────┴──────┘
```

### Custom function on a a single column/expression

We can also apply custom functions on single expressions, via `.apply` or `.map`.

Below is an example of how we can square a column with a custom function and with normal polars expressions. The expression syntax
should always be preferred, as its a lot faster.

```py
(df.group_by("g")
 .agg(
     pl.col("a").apply(lambda group: group**2).alias("squared1"),
     (pl.col("a")**2).alias("squared2")
 ))
```

#### what's the difference between `apply` and `map`?

`map` works on whole column `series`. `apply` works on single values, or single groups, dependent on the context.

###### `select` context:

- `map`

  - input/output type: `Series`
  - semantic meaning of input: a column value
- `apply`

  - input/output type: `Union[int, float, str, bool]`
  - semantic meaning of input: single values in a column

###### `group_by` context:

- `map`

  - input/output type: `Series`
  - semantic meaning of input: A list column where the values are the groups
- `apply`

  - input/output type: `Series`
  - semantic meaning of input: The groups

Comment: Thank @ritchie46. This got it perfectly.

Comment: Trying to get my head around `polars` which looks great. Is there a particular reason your function uses `args[0]` and `args[1]`rather than `x` and `y`.?Presumably both would work and I think usually named arguments are considered more Pythonic. Is your way idiomatic for `polars`?